# Constructing a Borel measurable function that assumes every real value in every sub-interval of (0,1)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

So, this is a homework problem I have no idea how to approach. Previous year assignment sheets suggest a way which is as follows:

Let $x ∈ (0, 1)$, and let $(x_i)_i≥1$ be its decimal expansion.
(If $x$ has several decimal expansions, use the one that terminates in 0.)

(a) Show that $f(x) = \limsup_n n^{-1} \cdot \#\{i = 1, \ldots , n \mid x_i = 7\}$
defines a Borel measurable function on the unit interval.

(b) Show that $f$ assumes every value in $[0, 1]$ on each nonempty subinterval $(a, b) ⊂ (0, 1)$.

(c) Construct a Borel measurable function that assumes every value in $[−∞,∞]$ on each
nonempty subinterval of $(0, 1)$.

Comment: How can I show that the set $E_n = \{x \mid 1/n #\{i = 1, 2, \ldots , n \ mid x_i = 7\} \geq \alpha \}$ is a Borel set for all real $\alpha$ where $x\in (0,1)$ has the decimal expansion $0. x_1 x_2 x_2 \ldots$